# How to make chain of Mono/Flux and implement Retry in sping-webflux

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I have a scenario with reactive/async call. I am using `spring-boot-starter-webflux` and using `webclient` to make external HTTP calls.
My scenario is I have to make a call to callA() and then check its response ResponseA. If its ResponseA is ok than exit and return ResponseA.
Otherwise create second request requestB using ResponseA and make a call to callB(). Then check its response ResponseB.
If it is ok then return ResponseA otherwise doRetry on callA().

```
public Mono<ResponseA> callA(Request1 requestA) {
    // calling service-A using webclient
}
public Flux<ResponseB> callB(Request2 requestB) { 
    // calling service-B using webclient but to create requestB, I need ResponseA.
}
```

Comment: You just put an if statement in a flatMap

Comment: Inside flatMap, after adding condition, I want to make a call to callB() and check its response. For checking callB() response, I have to subscribe to it. But issue is subscribe() does not return anything. So I will not able to chain these two operations. I am looking for a way where I can make a chain of two operations. First I will check responseB then return responseA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to do some if-statements in a `flatMap`. Probably split it up into some better function names etc. No subscribing, no blocking.

```
callA(createNewRequest()).flatMap(response1 -> {

    // Validate response
    if(!isValidResponse(response)) {

        // if failed validation, create new request and do a new call
        var request = buildRequest(response);
        return callB(request).flatMap(response2 -> {

                // validate second response
                if(!isValidResponse(response2)) {

                     // failed validation return the first response.
                     return Mono.just(response1)
                }

                // otherwise recursively call again
                return callA(createNewRequest()); // Warning this can be an infinite loop
            }
    }

    // Validation passed
    return Mono.just(response);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Thomas, Thanks for looking into my issue. I am trying to use this logic but I stuck as last line is giving me below compile-time error.
`no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that Flux<R> conforms to Mono<? extends R>`
// Validation passed
 return Mono.just(response); <-- this statement

Comment: it was not meant to be a straight off copy paste solution.... It means you are returning a Flux, when it wants a Mono, or the other way around... i recommend you read up on the basics of reactive programming. Returning correct stuff from functions is basic basic basic programming.

Comment: Thanks. I understand and correct it. I convert Flux< response2 > into Mono< response2>.

Comment: if this post helped you then please concider marking it as the correct answer.